# Cannot display selected name values on Material multi select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-hooks, material-ui

I use [Material Multiple select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#multiple-select) to select employees as shown on the following demo:

[sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-worker-wjr0b2)

However, I display id values of the selected employees, but I want to display names of the selected employees. For this purpose, I used another hook, called `names`, but still could not.

Here i the code (I cannot share on sandbox, but you can paste directly and check):

***demo.js:***

```js
import * as React from "react";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Rozele",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Pat",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Farlee",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Eddie",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Ingram",
  },
];

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([]);
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setIds(value);
    // I need to set names by matching value and employee id
    //setNames(employees.indexOf(...));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={ids}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {employees.map((employee) => (
            <MenuItem key={employee.id} value={employee.id}>
              <Checkbox checked={ids.includes(employee.id)} />
              <ListItemText primary={employee.name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another state to get the names of the employees. You can use a derived variable.

To display the correct name values in the input box we can use the `ids`.

```js
export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setIds(value);
  };

  // get all the selected employees and return their names
  const names = employees
    .filter((employee) => ids.includes(employee.id))
    .map((employee) => employee.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={ids}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            // select the name of the employees to show in the select input
            return selected
              .map(
                (id) => employees.find((employee) => employee.id === id).name
              )
              .join(",");
          }}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {employees.map((employee) => (
            <MenuItem key={employee.id} value={employee.id}>
              <Checkbox checked={ids.includes(employee.id)} />
              <ListItemText primary={employee.name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      {names.join(",")}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, but in that case `ids` values are names instead of id values. Any idea?

Comment: @ferry I understand what you're saying, I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Wonderfulll!!! Voted up and marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
import * as React from "react";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};

const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Rozele"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Pat"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Farlee"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Eddie"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Ingram"
  }
];

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event?.target?.value || []);
    // I need to set names by matching value and employee id
    //setNames(employees.indexOf(...));
  };

  const renderValue = (selected) =>
    selected?.map(({ name }) => name)?.join(", ");

  const isChecked = (selectedId) => {
    return !!value?.find(({ id }) => id === selectedId);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
          renderValue={renderValue}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {employees.map((employee) => (
            <MenuItem key={employee.id} value={employee}>
              <Checkbox checked={isChecked(employee.id)} />
              <ListItemText primary={employee.name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, almost done. Just a little problem. When value changed, `setValue(event?.target?.value || []);` set value by the previous selected values. I mean, for example you select one item, its value [], if you select one item more its value [1] instead of [1,2]. Any idea?

Comment: I've checked this code in sandbox, value variable stores array like that:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Rozele"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pat"
    }
].

So if you need only names, you can do:


value.map(({ name }) => name)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).